# All widgets look bad on Ubuntu 16, what is wrong?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, gui, gtk

Can any one help me with this? I don't even know what is wrong. If it's gnome or GTK or whatever... All widgets look like crap.

I have Ubuntu 16 and it was working fine. I noticed it started to look weird like this after I followed this [tutorial](http://homeonrails.com/2016/05/truecolor-in-gnome-terminal-tmux-and-neovim/) to make gnome support 24-bit color.

[image]

Comment: Is gnome-settings-daemon running? It looks like your're using a different WM, and not running a standard gnome-session, so probable that things aren't getting set up properly, giving you the default windows-esque widget styling, rather than the properly themed styling.

Comment: the problem is with arc-theme... other themes work alright... whats up?

Comment: No idea. Sounds like a bug with that theme. Ask the theme author perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You have added the repository of gnome3 and have installed  gnome3-staging and gnome3.

Run these commands to purge the repository.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Comment: Will not this remove GNOME as well? Looks like OP wants to use GNOME desktop.